# How to map reduce referential data in functional programming

Tags: haskell, clojure, functional-programming, monads

I want to make a tile based game using functional programming.

Game has 6 tiles and each tile can occupy a piece. Here's my data structure:

```
{
 :pieces {
          1 { :type 'p' }
          2 { :type 'r' }
          }
 :tiles [{}
         {}
         {:current 1}
         {}
         {:current 2}
         {}]
 }
```

This is a serial representation of the game tiles:

```
'00p0r0'
```

I need a function that transforms this serial data into my data structure.

Comment: first of all please pick a language in your tags?  the map there looks like clojure - so how comes haskell into play?  also please add the coude you have tried so far.

Comment: language doesn't matter, i want to know how you do this in functional style. @cfrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to optimize this but it should give you the right idea. See below code for alternate suggestion.

The interesting thing here is you are mapping a fixed tile model over a variable piece type set. There would be efficiency in making the piece model a fixed array as well.

***Note:*** the input needs to be a string and not using single quotes as in your example: (e.g. `"00p0r0"` vs. `'00p0r0'`).

```
(def empty-tile-map
  {:piece-count 0
   :pieces {}
   :tiles (into [] (repeat 6 {}))})

(defn set-tile
  "Sets the tile to the index reference to piece"
  [arref indx value]
  (assoc arref indx {:current value}))

(defn string-to-board-reducer
  "Reduce function to create pieces and reference in tile"
  [{:keys [piece-count tcount tiles] :as acc} x]
  (let [ccnt   (inc piece-count)
        nmap   (assoc acc :tcount (inc tcount))]
    (if (> (int x) 48)
      (assoc 
        (assoc
          (update-in nmap [:pieces] assoc ccnt {:type x})
          :tiles (set-tile tiles tcount ccnt))
        :piece-count ccnt)
      nmap)
    ))

(defn string-to-board
  [s]
  "Take serializated string and generate board"
  (dissoc (reduce string-to-board-reducer 
                  (assoc empty-tile-map :tcount 0) (seq s))
          :tcount))
```

**Alternate**
By definition, the input string implicitly contains all the information you want. A series of functions could be defined that work with the serialize string as the board state, replacing it with a new string as you go. Just a suggestion.